# Property of one type map to another type of instance

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using automapper for mapping view models and entity models with each other, all was good, but now i have a little different scenario where AutoMapper is not able to map my types.

My View Model:

```
   public class CriminalSearchViewModel
   {

    public CriminalSearchParamsViewModel SearchParameters { get; set; }

    public SelectList GenderSelectList { get; set; }

    public SelectList NationalitySelectList { get; set; }

    public SelectList CrimeSelectList { get; set; }

    public SelectList CriminalStatusSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

second view model:

```
public class CriminalSearchParamsViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int? GenderID { get; set; }

    public int? StatusID { get; set; }

    public string CNIC { get; set; }

    public int? AgeFrom { get; set; }

    public int? AgeTo { get; set; }

    public double? Height { get; set; }

    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public int? NationalityID { get; set; }
}
```

and my Business Model:

```
public class CriminalSearch
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int? GenderID { get; set; }

    public int? StatusID { get; set; }

    public string CNIC { get; set; }

    public int? AgeFrom { get; set; }

    public int? AgeTo { get; set; }

    public double? Height { get; set; }

    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public int? NationalityID { get; set; }

}
```

I have defined mapping like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CriminalSearch, CriminalSearchParamsViewModel>();
```

also tried this as well:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<CriminalSearchParamsViewModel,CriminalSearchViewModel>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.SearchParameters, opt =>
     opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<CriminalSearchParamsViewModel, CriminalSearch>(src)));
```

and in controller i am trying like:

```
public ActionResult Search(CriminalSearchViewModel searchVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var searchParams = searchVM.SearchParameters;
        var criminalSearch = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CriminalSearch>(searchParams);
        _criminalService.SearchCriminals(criminalSearch);
    }
        return View();
}
```

But it always throws exception:

> > Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
> >
> > Mapping types:
> >     CriminalSearchParamsViewModel -> CriminalSearch
> >     NationalCriminals.UI.ViewModels.CriminalSearchParamsViewModel -> NationalCriminals.Core.Models.CriminalSearch
> >
> > Destination path:
> >     CriminalSearch
> >
> > Source value:
> >     NationalCriminals.UI.ViewModels.CriminalSearchParamsViewModel

Anybody can pint me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the order of the generic args in the method `CreateMap`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CriminalSearchParamsViewModel,CriminalSearch>()
```

Thats because the first generic arg is the **Source** type and the second is the **Destination**, it is not two way, you must to declare the both if you want to map from a type to another and viceversa like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CriminalSearchParamsViewModel,CriminalSearch>()
Mapper.CreateMap<CriminalSearch,CriminalSearchParamsViewModel>()
```

The method `CreateMap` is described like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>();
```

> Suggest: [Using AutoMapper: Creating Mappings](http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/)